# How can i bind this and where do i bind it?

Tags: javascript, html, controls, bind

I keep getting a consoel error: Unexpected token this

Where should i bind to make this function work?

```
        this.Map = new Button({ //button is a control so dont worry if it doesn't make sense
            text: "Map",
            press: function(event){
                pop.open(this._Map);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind this into your press function, like this:

```
function onPress(event){
    pop.open(this._Map);
}

this.Map = new Button({
    text: "Map",
    press: onPress.bind(this)
})
```

Or you can also use this approach:

```
var _this = this;
this.Map = new Button({ 
    text: "Map",
    press: function(event){
        pop.open(_this._Map);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use the `new` keyword, the interpreter creates a new empty object and call the constructor (here Button) with that new object bound to it
so the "`this`" keyword inside the constructor is not the same as the this of `this.map`

and since your are not explicitly calling `Button()` you cannot bind this.
you can do as follow:

```
 var self = this;
 this.Map = new Button({ 
            text: "Map",
            press: function(event){
                pop.open(self._Map);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ES6 syntax:

```
 press: (event) => {
     pop.open(this._Map);
 }
```

Read here about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)